# Oracle SQL: Anyone can help me with Error(2,32): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'WORKED_HOURS'

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Anyone can help me with Error(2,32): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'WORKED_HOURS'

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER uprava_prac_casu
    BEFORE
    UPDATE OF worked_hours
    ON Attendance_of_employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (:new.worked_hours>15) THEN :worked_hours:=15; END IF;

    IF (:new.worked_hours<3) THEN :worked_hours:=3; END IF;
    END;
    /


Trigger UPRAVA_PRAC_CASU compiled

Errors: check compiler log
```

From compiler log: Error(2,32): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'WORKED_HOURS'

Then I have tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER uprava_prac_casu
    BEFORE
    UPDATE OF worked_hours
    ON Attendance_of_employee
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (:new.worked_hours>15) THEN :old.worked_hours:=15; END IF;

    IF (:new.worked_hours<3) THEN :old.worked_hours:=3; END IF;
    END;
    /




> Error report -
>     ORA-04085: nemožno zmeniť hodnotu referenčnej premennej OLD
>     04085. 00000 -  "cannot change the value of an OLD reference variable"
>     *Cause:    Old values can only be read and not changed.
>     *Action:   Do not attempt to change an old variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just have your "old"s and "new"s set up backward.  Or, you may want to adjust the "new" values.  I am guessing the latter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER uprava_prac_casu
BEFORE UPDATE OF worked_hours
ON Attendance_of_employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:new.worked_hours > 15) THEN :new.worked_hours := 15; END IF;
    IF (:new.worked_hours < 3) THEN :new.worked_hours := 3; END IF;
END;
```

You are getting the error because you can only update the new value in the trigger, not the old value.

Answer (score 0):

AS it clearly says you cannot modify `:old.worked_hours`.

> You cannot change the field values of the OLD structure; attempting to
>   do so will raise the ORA-04085 error. You can modify the field values
>   of the NEW structure.